# Error 404 when serving files in angularjs and node app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes, ngroute

I have

```
<base href="/!#/">
```

at the top of my **index.html** file. When I go to URL `http://localhost:5000/` everything works fine, it instantly add `#!/` so the URL is `http://localhost:5000/#!/` and page display as expected.

At the server side I have following code which should allow me to use my files

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Structure of my files is something like:

```
bookApp(folder)
  server.js
  public(folder)
    index.html
    app.js(ngRoute)
    views(folder)
    css(folder)
    controllers(folder)
```

and my AngularJS routing is:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])
    .config(config);

function config ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'PostsCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/posts.html'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            controller: 'registerCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
        })
        .otherwise('/');
}
})();
```

The very first page *(views/posts.html)* load as expected but when I click

```
<li><a href="/login" title="Login to bookApp">Sign in</a></li>
```

the URL is `http://localhost:5000/login` not as like I thought `http://localhost:5000/!#/login`.

and it display:

> Cannot GET /login

when I manually change URL to `http://localhost:5000/#!/login` it works fine.

How to fix this behavior?

The only solution I see is to get rid of `<base>` tag and in every link manually in `href` directive add *!#* before slash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forgetting the ng-view directive: `<div ng-view></div>` which is the container for the content that is provided by your routing. Place this above your script if you have everything contained in one file.

You can also try:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
<div class="ng-view"></div>
```

Is there any particular reason you are still using Angular 1? I know this isn't technically answering your question, but I would highly recommend that you start using the latest Angular. You can still keep legacy code but it will make a lot of what you are doing a lot cleaner and clear.

Comment: That is not my problem at all, I was using `ng-view` all the time. I do not know why I did have issue like this but i finished with just editing my *href* directive into one with **#/** prefix. I use angularJS because it is nice, I know it pretty well and it is good for large application with multiple DOM interference like this one I'm developing now.